# ErrorPageSecurityFilter not present

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, swagger

microService=undefined,SpringApplication,handleRunFailure,815 | Unable to close ApplicationContext
java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.filter.ErrorPageSecurityFilter not present
at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeNamedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:117)
at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:125)
at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49)
at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.reifyTypeArguments(Reifier.java:68)
at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:138)
at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49)
at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.repository.MethodRepository.computeReturnType(MethodRepository.java:75)
at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.repository.MethodRepository.getReturnType(MethodRepository.java:66)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.getGenericReturnType(Method.java:292)
at org.springframework.core.MethodParameter.getGenericParameterType(MethodParameter.java:510)
at org.springframework.core.SerializableTypeWrapper$MethodParameterTypeProvider.getType(SerializableTypeWrapper.java:291)
at org.springframework.core.SerializableTypeWrapper.forTypeProvider(SerializableTypeWrapper.java:107)
at org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.forType(ResolvableType.java:1421)
at org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.forMethodParameter(ResolvableType.java:1342)
at org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.forMethodParameter(ResolvableType.java:1324)
at org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.forMethodParameter(ResolvableType.java:1291)
at org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.forMethodReturnType(ResolvableType.java:1236)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:830)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:703)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:674)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1670)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:570)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:542)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:667)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:659)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBeansOfType(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1300)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getExitCodeFromMappedException(SpringApplication.java:886)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getExitCodeFromException(SpringApplication.java:874)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleExitCode(SpringApplication.java:861)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleRunFailure(SpringApplication.java:802)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:348)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1332)
at com.safaricom.microservice.activityPlanner.ActivityPlannerApplication.main(ActivityPlannerApplication.java:10)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.filter.ErrorPageSecurityFilter
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398)
at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeNamedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:114)
... 38 common frames omitted

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it, was using springboot version 2.6.2 but swagger version to, Just changed to swagger 3 and it sorted it.